# To Display the List Data that is fetched from Databse Into a List View in Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing a simple Android application where I need to display the fetched result from a database query into a list view in java.
I am not getting the data in the layout of the list view. Can you help me to resolve this?
In List View Output, I get Data as Contact@5accd4 instead of Subash as Output. Can I know how to get the List data that is fetched after calling getAllContacts() function into a ListView using Arrayadaptor.

The Code For the query is

```
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                // contact.setPeriod(cursor.getString(3));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }
```

The MainActivity Java Code For putting in ListView is

```
public class Bus extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHandler db;
List<Contact> contacts;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bus);
        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        contacts = db.getAllContacts();
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(this, R.layout.listview,  R.id.textview, contacts);
        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.buslist);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

The MainActivity.xml is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Bus">
 <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/buslist">

 </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The Listview.xml file code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp">

    </TextView>
```

The Contact.java code is

```
public class Contact {
    int _id;
    String _name;
    String _phone_number;

    public Contact(){   }
    public Contact(int id, String name, String _phone_number){
        this._id = id;
        this._name = name;
        this._phone_number = _phone_number;

    }

    public Contact(String name, String _phone_number){
        this._name = name;
        this._phone_number = _phone_number;

    }
    public int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }

    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this._name;
    }


    public void setName(String name){
        this._name = name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber(){
        return this._phone_number;
    }


    public void setPhoneNumber(String phone_number){
        this._phone_number = phone_number;
    }

}
```

Comment: Refer https://abhiandroid.com/ui/arrayadapter-tutorial-example.html example for using array adapter, also check weather getAllContacts giving you any results or not

Comment: Ya getAllContacts is fetching all results

Comment: But For me, it is data not get populated in list view.

Comment: I get data as com.example.mapdistance.Database.Contact@5ccc8bc4.Contact@5cc8bc4